# Java audio converter api

Tags: audio, java, audio-converter

I am looking for a comprehensive API in Java that can convert audio across various formats and bitrates.

For example
WAV (6kHz to 48kHz) L16/audio ---TO--- WAV (RIFF header) 8KHz 8-bit mono A-law/U-law
AIFF (6kHz to 48kHz) L16/audio ---TO--- WAV (RIFF header) 8KHz 8-bit mono A-law/U-law

and other voice audio formats.

Any other suggestions about similar Java libraries on audio conversion are also entertained.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6609358/convert-sound-file-into-wav-with-specific-bitrate-and-cut-specific-part-of-the-f

Comment: thanks Raveesh Sharma, I agree with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5717447/convert-16-bit-pcm-to-8-bit), but still the problem of reducing the frequency like from 46khz to 8khz to Alaw and Ulaw remains. I am looking for a library that can comprehensively provide an API to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by using [Tritonus : Open Source Java Sound API](http://www.tritonus.org/plugins.html) and its wide range of [sound convertor plugins](http://www.tritonus.org/plugins.html).

Specifically the Tritonus miscellaneous plugins was very useful in my context.

Comment: I counted three audio conversion plugins. I wouldn't call that a "wide range of sound convertor plugins".